# Height of content div not increasing with the contents inside dive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a simple HTML structure based on Foundation 5, With Header, Content & Footer section.

One of the section inside "Content" area will show four `Div's` in each row and i can have multiple rows with max of 4 div's in each row showing image & some text etc..

These div's will adjust based on screen size as showing in the fiddle example.

My issue right now is that Content div is not increasing with the size of the "content" div and footer section is also showing at after header section hiding the content section

http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the content class:

http://jsfiddle.net/UHqWF/12/

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:15px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Why it doesnt it adjust to height without `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker because the items inside it are using float. So it is not impacting the layout of its parent and siblings in the same way a non-floated element would. `overflow: hidden` clears the floats: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/